# Pervasive pivot data

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I have a table with in there following data

```html
ID|LabelID|Value
1 |1      |3
1 |2      |1
1 |3      |15
2 |1      |5
2 |2      |7
2 |3      |5
```

I want to get the following as result within a pervasive database

```html
ID|Label1|Label2|Label3
1 |3     |1     |15
2 |5     |7     |5
```

Anyone an idea? I did try some things and the best result I can get is the following:

```html
ID|Label1|Label2|Label3
1 |3     |      |
1 |      |1     |
1 |      |      |15
2 |5     |      |
2 |      |7     |
2 |      |      |5
```

Comment: What does your query look like?  What version of PSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have fun... :-)

Should work in most versions of SQL. There are vendor specific PIVOT statements which are also an option.

This was the way to do it prior to PIVOT clause.

```
drop table #test;
create table #test (ID int, LabelID int, Value int);

insert into #test values (1, 1, 3)
,(1, 2, 1)
,(1, 3, 15)
,(2, 1, 5)
,(2, 2, 7)
,(2, 3, 5);

select ID
      ,sum(case when LabelID = 1 then Value else null end) as Label1
      ,sum(case when LabelID = 2 then Value else null end) as Label2
      ,sum(case when LabelID = 3 then Value else null end) as Label3
  from #test
group by ID;
```

Comment: Here is how to do it using PIVOT...

select ID
      ,[1] as Label1
      ,[2] as Label2
      ,[3] as Label3
  from #test
pivot (sum (Value) for LabelID in ([1],[2],[3])) as XYX

Comment: Pervasive PSQL does not support PIVOT.

Comment: I hadn't heard of Pervasive SQL until now. Does the example/style that I posted work in PSQL; I guess it should? mirtheil, your query also works in SQL Server. It requires 3 nested loops according to the SQL Server execution plan versus none in the example I posted.

Comment: Cool , always refreshing to see how portable sql is.

Comment: This one is working nice and fast! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that worked for me.

```
create table psqlPivot (id integer, labelid integer, val integer);
insert into psqlPivot values (1, 1,3);
insert into psqlPivot values (1, 2,1);
insert into psqlPivot values (1, 3,15);
insert into psqlPivot values (2, 1,5);
insert into psqlPivot values (2, 2,7);
insert into psqlPivot values (2, 3,5);

select distinct v.id, (select a.val as label1 from psqlPivot a where a.labelid = 1 and a.id = v.id)
,(select b.val as label2 from psqlPivot b where b.labelid = 2 and b.id = v.id)
,(select c.val as label3 from psqlPivot c where c.labelid = 3 and c.id = v.id)
from psqlpivot v
```

Comment: Tried this and worked but took quite a while to load the data (4 selects takes too much time)